# How to create an entity with multiple queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a database-first Entity Framework model.
In the database there's a table of matrixed rows and my application is supposed to display and perform CRUD operations on it.
For the sake of simplicity, I want to create an entity to track a specific set of values, and make changes to the database.
Can I hook this entity up to the database so that it tracks each change I make?

The following entity accepts a list of values and transforms them into an flat object.  Ultimately, I'd like to change the constructor to access the database directly (given a few more parameters) and then be able to update the specific values for each property on a save.

Here's my sample entity:

```
public class ServiceAdjustment
    {
        public string UNIT { get; set; }
        public string INFIND { get; set; }
        public string VASTREET { get; set; }
        public string VALNOSTR { get; set; }
        public string VALSEWER { get; set; }
        public string VALWATER { get; set; }
        public string VALCURB { get; set; }
        public string VALSWK { get; set; }
        public string STSZ { get; set; }
        public string STLSM { get; set; }
        public string STND_DPT { get; set; }
        public string VALDELTA { get; set; }
        public string VALNABLA { get; set; }
        //constructor
        public ServiceAdjustment(List<LANDADJT> landadjts)
        {
            UNIT = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "UNIT").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            INFIND = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "INFIND").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            VASTREET = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "VASTREET").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            VALNOSTR = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "VALNOSTR").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            VALSEWER = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "VALSEWER").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            VALWATER = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "VALWATER").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            VALCURB = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "VALCURB").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            VALSWK = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "VALSWK").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            STSZ = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "STSZ").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            STLSM = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "STLSM").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            STND_DPT = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "STND_DPT").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            VALDELTA = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "VALDELTA").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            VALNABLA = landadjts.Where(x => x.TABLE_NAME == "VALNABLA").Select(x => x.CODE).FirstOrDefault<string>();
        }
    }
```

How can I hook this up to the database so that when a save is made on the UNIT property, it updates the value tied to it in the LANDADJT table?

Answer (score 0):

see this:

```
 dbcontext.YourEntity.Add(new ServiceAdjustment(<yourlandadjtsVariableHere>));
 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

---

If you need to track entity, you can use

```
var entity = new YourEntityClass();
var entity.PrimaryKeyColumn = 1234;
context.YourDbSet.Attach(entity);
```

now your entity is attached to `ChangeTracker`. Now you can change any value and save it

```
entity.SomeProp = "John Doe";
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

you can check the state of your entity by

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).State
```

Comment: This looks like it's saving the entity to the database, not each item in the list to a different row of a table.  If I made a change to the UNIT property and then saved it, would it track the change in the LANDADJT table or a theoretical table which represents my entity?